# Create an Icon or Symbol to compare of human ages at the same row ??? (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37BRx.jpg)

Such as exactly of a picture above where we could took to have a look to comparison about symbolic of human ages and then combined them with their names. This which one we could look at to the  Column "B" . That's just for an example for took a definition be clearly I made it with input them one by one by typing it by manually.  I have hard work arround about it. and these all makes me really frustate about how to make them to become Automatically.  I attach this my attempt was before :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ChxC8A5WycrMNveLRzJAxAc1SmFxELbUpjL1JVmI4sE/edit?usp=sharing

## Sorry, about my english and I hope you'll be understand and help me soon any help would makes me happy to appreciate  !

Comment: I treid but it's so difficult to understand. Can you provide more simple example? Like this: input A -> desired output for A, input B -> desired output B, and so on.

Comment: I just want to change the symbolic to identifying ages of human and also according with their gender too. Like the exactly persist on the "column A" (ONLY CHANGE THE ICON OR SYMBOL. NO MATTER WITH THEIR NAMES) The Answer like I tried on the "column U & V"  ???

Comment: Do you want icons which are small images or pictures?

Comment: small images now I was updated my spreadsheet doc Please.. pay attenion just to the "column A"  until  "Column D" and the icon or symbolic should be considering or depends on to the description on the "Column A".  Convert the "Column B" to become a Symbolic of Human Ages!

Comment: I took function from column Y: `=join( char(10); filter('Data table'!I2:I; 'Data table'!A2:A = 1 ) )` and changed `I` to `G`  new function:  `=join( char(10); filter('Data table'!G2:G; 'Data table'!A2:A = 1 ) )`

Comment: Sandy Good. Thanks anyway!  I know some user in here or from other threads has helped me but until now I did't find to figure out this yet until the Answer would be find a simple way or using the formulas with an Automatically I mean array to down by it self.  In that case the Answer who has given at the "column Y"  by someone it has still manually typing by input the formulas one by one.